# Have a bootstrap ad modal appear on page load every six hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

Here's the site I'm working on (it's all a bit sloppy right now, so my apologies):
http://spectrumdesigns.co/Basketball/

Essentially I have a modal called "ad-modal" that I want to pop up on page load for the user, but then not pop up again until 6+ hours later.

I used the following code to attempt to do this (from looking at other sources) alongside the jquery.cookie.js script. Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
             $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
         $('#ad-modal').reveal();
     }
 });
</script>
```

and here's the html of #ad-modal

```
<div class="modal modal-fullscreen ad fade" id="ad-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="modal" style="color: #ffffff;z-index: 99;">X</a>
    <img src="images/550ad.jpg" class="center hidden-xs"  width="100%" height="auto" style="max-width: 550px">
    <img src="images/300by450ad.jpg" class="center visible-xs"  width="100%" height="auto" style="max-width: 300px"><br />
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hidden-md hidden-lg" data-dismiss="modal" href="#" style="position: absolute;right: 10px;bottom:10px;">Close</button></p>


</div>
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: Essentially the modal doesn't pop up at all, even if it's your first time visiting the site (unless I'm not testing this correctly)

Comment: Show us the html of `#ad-modal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one. Tested and it work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (!$.cookie("modal_shown")) {
    var expire = new Date(Date.now() + 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', {
      expires: expire,
      path: '/'
    });
    $('#ad-modal').modal();
  }

});
```

and change ur jquery cookie.js from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js.

I found that ur jquery.cookie.js has problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it. I appreciate the effort, though!

Comment: Nevermind, I edited my answer. It tested and it work.

Comment: Yes - that did it! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [carhartl/jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie),

The `expires` option accepts a `Number` or `Date` object. To create a cookie that will expire 6 hours from now, you just pass `new Date(Date.now() + 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` to it.

Also the method to call a modal is just `modal()` not `reveal()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$.cookie('modal_shown')) {
      $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000), path: '/' });
      $('#ad-modal').modal();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help with the 6 hours thing. However, the modal still isn't popping up for me when visiting the site (testing this by going incognito)

Comment: the update didn't fix the issue, but I truly appreciate you putting in all of this effort.